# Regex: match all words from string that doesn't contain underscore

Tags: javascript, regex

My input is for example `"ghj, klj! ab-CDE-fg_hi"`.

When I use `\w+` pattern I get `["ghk", "klj", "ab", "CDE", "fg_hi"]`.

I need to get this array `["ghk", "klj", "ab", "CDE"]`.

How can I get the wanted output?

Comment: There's more here you are not telling us. For example, you are splitting on `-` and spaces, and dropping `!`'s and `,`'s, which means you need to describe the problem domain more for us. Sure, you could do some regex like `[^_]*` to find matches that don't have an underscore, but we need more info on what we can do since what I said will not help solve the problem based on the input and output provided. Also, is this for a particular language?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. We should only match the parts of string that contain English letters. So we should ignore any symbols, underscores, hyphens. I will use this regex in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for word boundaries and a character class:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]+\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/wOT2z6/1/).